# Windows 8.1 using bootcamp keyboard causes glitches at login

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1, boot-camp

This might be a long shot.

Gear:
* Windows 8.1
* 2013 Macbook Pro Retina
* Using bootcamp

After boot I log in and everything appears normal, I can launch apps and do most things.  But... the second I press any key the keyboard goes into a non-responsive mode.  If I type in notepad what I pressed will not appear, if I hit a bunch of keys maybe every 10th or so will appear eventually, maybe after 5-10 seconds.  This is only the keyboard, I can continue to use the mouse and launch apps but the keyboard is completely unresponsive.  The only other thing that is effected is if I right click on the desktop the context menu takes a few seconds to appear.  Other than that I don't notice anything else wrong.

This goes on for a while until all the various things have loaded and then I can type (maybe 45 seconds).  It's inconsistent in how long this lasts and how severe the delay is, it seems to have to do with when I first press the keyboard.

I have disabled every startup item and the only effect it appears to have is that the length the keyboard is 'stuck' seems shorter (subjective).

If I launch task manager nothing really sticks out.  CPU and disk rarely hit 50% and the boot happens fairly quickly (except for the keyboard).

As I said, this may be a long shot.  I'm interested on both what might be causing this or what I might do to troubleshoot.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting your Computer and waiting a few minutes should remove any rogue processes. You can use the Safe Mode to Troubleshoot.

Often, you would like to see if there's any log using the Common Log viewer for Windows.

Restore points may return your computer to a more usable state. Be sure to Save any Important data after the restore point if you don't want to re-install some software that are definitively not malware.

If my CPU rate changed suddenly, I would see first if there's conflicting hardware then I would scan my computer for rootkits, malware and registry corruption. That is often the most common problems for lag.

Applications build lag only at start up because they all want to start at same time. Malicious applications that are often using internet (free apps), make pop-ups, scan for updates are also a possible cause.

Anti-Virus make peaks in memory and CPU when they are scanning. You could disable the Auto-Protection and Daily Scan Features.